Do the original manuscripts of Plautus have stage directions?
I notice that the English text of Loeb Classical Library editions of Plautus contain stage directions but the Latin text on the facing page does not include them. Is this because the stage directions are not actually present in the original manuscripts and are just the inventions of modern editors to help the reader better understand the text or have the Loeb editors omitted the stage directions from their editions even though they are present in the mss?

see also this question https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/what-is-the-oldest-preserved-stage-direction

In general, plays may or may not have stage directions preserved. Even when some are present, the LOEB editions and other translations may expand upon them to help with the understanding of the passage by setting the scene stating who are the actors, and even perhaps what they are wearing, where the scene is set, further stage directions..
For Plautus, looking at the play Amphitruo , Amphitryon, the Latin text at PHI begins

Mercvrivs Vt vos in vostris voltis mercimoniis emundis

One Loeb edition begins with

PROLOGUE Enter Mercury dressed as a slave, wearing a hat with little wings.
Mer. As you wish me to you give you rich gain in the buying

Another Loeb edition begins with a list of Dramatis Personae and no stage directions.
In the Introduction to this AMPHITRYON Latin Text and translation by Paul Nixon, 1916.

Welcome as a full autobiography of Plautus would be, in place of such scant and tasteless biographical morsels as we do have, only less welcome, perhaps, would be his own stage directions for his plays, supposing him to have written stage directions and to have written them with something more than even modern fullness.

Latin for the plays Plautus, are at PHI Latin Texts and entering Plautus in the Authors and selecting Titus Maccius Plautus will allow selection of the original Latin for the play.
W. M. Lindsay, An Introduction to Latin Textual Emendation, 1896 lists manuscripts sources for the collation of the latin text for Plautus in the Section Introductions, in the subsection The manuscripts of Plautus. This states photography facsimiles are given in Part I of Chatelain's Paléographie des Classiques latins which is available at Illinois Library Digital Collection.

The problem with using the PHI Latin Texts (and to a lesser extent Loebs) for this sort of thing is that their texts are cleaned up to an unknown degree and don't include a critical apparatus. You could use the same argument to say the manuscripts for Amphitruo don't start with two argumenta, but they do; Leo's edition, which the PHI text is based on, even includes them, but the PHI version cuts them off.

@Cairnarvon Good Point, though not including it as an easily accessible source for the Latin text I thought would be worse, at which point you go to other books (another book link had already been included) or the MS (links for the manuscript names had already been included). How  can the answer be improved?

The quote from Nixon is really the only part of your answer that answers the question, if slightly obliquely. Any substantial discussion of attested ancient stage directions (which we do have for some plays by other authors!) and what we think must have existed for Plautus or how and why the modern reconstructed directions came about (I know there's literature available, I just haven't been able to look at it myself) would go a long way towards making it feeling less like essentially a grope in the dark.

(Also, did you actually look at Chatelain? It doesn't have full manuscripts, just a sample of individual pages to give an impression of what manuscripts looked like in a given era, so it can't really show that there weren't any stage directions anywhere in the manuscripts. It's a pedagogical tool for palaeographers in training, not an archival record.)
